# Created multiple block devices in custom AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-devops

I have created one custom AMI after updated my EC2 Windows Server(Sysprep without Shutdown). After AMI Creation, I could see the mapping multiple block devices on AMI. I don't know why its creating multiple block devices whereas old AMI doesn't create multiple block devices. Can any one help me?

[image: my customized AMI]

Comment: How did  you create the image? Packer?

Comment: I just created AMI using AWS console only.